# If parent slug equals

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

I'm trying to write an if statement where, if a child page's has a slug equal to a specific value, a different statement is echoed. Regardless of the slug value, the function always returns the *else* value rather than any other.

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent->post_name);
    if ($post_data == 'slug-one'){
        $ticket = 'Cats';
    } elseif ($post_data == 'slug-two') {
        $ticket = 'Dogs';   
    } else {
        $ticket = 'Birds';  
    }

    echo $ticket;
?>
```

Any ideas as to how I can better write the statement, or what the error occurring is?

Comment: Without seeing the `get_post()` function we're operating blindly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I suspect it's [this one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/)

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/ ?

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($post_data)` and see what you got back... hwoever, shouldn't you be calling `get_slug` or something, because get_post() is going to return everything about a post, not just a slug.

Comment: Won't $post_data be a post object? Can you compare it that object to a string slug and expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I shouldn't have called `$post_data = get_post($post->post_parent->post_name)`. My fixed code is below. Thanks for the advice everyone.

```
<?php 
global $post;
$post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);

if ($post_data->post_name == 'in-the-city'){
    $ticket = 'Cats';
} elseif ($post_data->post_name == 'on-the-beach') {
    $ticket = 'Dogs';   
} else {
    $ticket = 'Birds';  
}

echo $ticket;
?>
```